# Проблема с if конструкцией

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def easy(utext):
    convert_to_list = list(utext)
    print(convert_to_list)
    lenght = len(convert_to_list)
    s = abc[::-1]
    for i in convert_to_list:
        a = 0
        if convert_to_list[:a] == abc[:a]:
            new_generate_pass = []
            #s = abc[::-1]
            new_generate_pass.append(s[a])
            print (new_generate_pass)
        a = a + 1  
utext = input("Введите ваше слово: ")
```

Вообщем такая проблема, по задумке когда попадаем в if
два списка должны сравнивать свои значения по индексам и если есть одинаковые буквы "а" (к примеру) то должен выполняться код ниже. Но независимо есть совпадения букв или нет он выполняет все что описанно в if

Answer (score 1):

этот код

```
a = 0
if convert_to_list[:a] == abc[:a]
```

означает

```
if convert_to_list[:0] == abc[:0]
```

а `list[:0]` - это список нулевого размера (срез с 0 элемента до 0 элемента НЕ ВКЛЮЧИТЕЛЬНО)

вы **ВСЕГДА** (a перед проверкой устанавливается в 0) проверяете срезы двух списков, размер которых 0 - конечно же они всегда равны

подозреваю, что ваш код должен был выглядеть так:

```
a = 0
for i in convert_to_list:
    if convert_to_list[a] == abc[a]:
        new_generate_pass = []
        #s = abc[::-1]
        new_generate_pass.append(s[a])
        print (new_generate_pass)
    a = a + 1
```

да и тут есть вопрос к тому, что происходит внутри `if`:

вы создаете новый список `new_generate_pass`, заносите в него один элемент `s[a]` и выводите это на экран

т.е. из-за того, что внутри `if` вы создаете список, то вы его в принципе никогда больше чем на 1 элемент и не накопите :)

Comment: Я вас понял, спасибо большое! Еще такой вопрос, чтобы накопить элементы в новом списке, мне следует его вынести с конструкции if , но оставить в цикле for ?

Comment: нет - тогда он так же будет содержать или 0 (`if` не сработал или `1` элемент), вам его надо вынести выше. А вообще вы бы описали задачу свою, чтобы понять что именно вам нужно, потому что тогда и код можно сделать более эффективно

Comment: В общем, задумка всей программы в том чтобы получить любое слово от пользователя, к примеру пусть будет "hello", после есть список с английским алфавитом который должен взять букву по индексу 0 и вместо "h" поставить "а"
так как 0-вой индекс будет хранить букву а после цикл должен вернуться в начало, увеличить индекс на +1 и повторить все заново пока все слово "hello" не превратится во что-то другое

Comment: все равно не понял, а можете привести пример есть слово `hello`, есть английский алфавит (26 букв) и что должно происходить с `hello`? в `abcde` превратиться должен?

Comment: Вообщем брать со списка букву (алгоритм ещё не придумал) который допустим видит букву "а" и меняет ее на "j"

Comment: а какая именно логика соответствия? почему `a` соответствует `j`?

Comment: Это как пример, пытаюсь научиться программировать на питоне и решил поставить себе задачу такую что со списка с буквами вытягивается случайная и заменяет букву в слове который ввел пользователь